# Python GoogleSearch module error : "TypeError: search() got an unexpected keyword argument 'tld' "

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-search

Here is my code, it was working properly before I was not getting an error while using it. I don't understand how it happened even though I didn't change with it. :

```
    results = []
for query in my_list:
    results.append(search(query, tld="com", num=1, stop=1, pause=2))
```

Error:

```
results.append(search(query, tld="com", num=1, stop=1, pause=2))
TypeError: search() got an unexpected keyword argument 'tld'
```

Comment: show the definition of `search`

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't understand what you were asking about by definition.
But this is the library I use:
[link](https://pypi.org/project/googlesearch-python/)

Comment: hey found the solution and added it here. If you install the `pip install googlesearch-python` , it will modify the original google module which causes these issues. I tested in my local system. Find my answer below and try it once again.

Comment: It is against Google's [Webmaster Guidelines](//developers.google.com/search/docs/advanced/guidelines/webmaster-guidelines) and [terms of service](//policies.google.com/terms/archive/20020906?hl=en) to submit programmatic search queries. Running this code against Google is likely to cause Google to show captcha for searches from your IP address.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is from the `google` python package. it is still working of all the versions.

#### version parameters :

- `query` : query string that we want to search for.
- `tld` : tld stands for top level domain which means we want to search our result on google.com or google.in or some other domain.
- `lang` : lang stands for language.
- `num` : Number of results we want.
- `start` : First result to retrieve.
- `stop` : Last result to retrieve. Use None to keep searching forever.
- `pause`: Lapse to wait between HTTP requests. Lapse too short may cause Google to block your IP. Keeping significant lapse will make your program slow but its safe and better option.
- `Return` : Generator (iterator) that yields found URLs. If the stop parameter is None the iterator will loop forever.

#### Here is your real problem:

There is one more python package with the module name as `googlesearch`

Link [here](https://pypi.org/project/googlesearch-python/)

Since it might be installed on your environment, this might be calling this module which does not have these parameters included.

#### The BlockBuster Solution is: (tested these both packages on local)

- Delete your Python Environment
- Create a new one
- install `pip install beautifulsoup4` and `pip install google`
- Now use your code which will work like charm.
- Never install the `pip install googlesearch-python` python package

Comment: Well, I assumed OP would be able to answer a question right about the code he is using.

Answer (score 1):

It is necessary to install the `google` library, installing this library stopped producing the error:

```
pip install google
```